# Serilog SQL Sink Log Server Name and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as columns

Tags: serilog

My application is running on a load balanced web server environment. Also, in lower environments, the SQL database for logging is shared across multiple environments. I would like to record server name and environment name as two separate columns in addition to the default columns. How do I configure the SQL server sink in the startup.cs?

These columns are not the part of [the standard columns](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#standard-columns) supported by the sink.

Below is current schema, with two extra columns ...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Logs]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Logs]
END
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    [Environment] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [ServerName] [nvarchar](60) NULL,

    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MessageTemplate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Level] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Properties] [xml] NULL,
    [LogEvent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

From the documentation, it looks like I need to configure the column something as following ... (For some reason, their documentation does not seem to up to date with Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer version 5.1.2)

Here what I think I need to use

```
var sqlLogTableColumnOptions = new ColumnOptions
{
    AdditionalDataColumns = new Collection<DataColumn>
    {
        new DataColumn{ ColumnName = "Environment", DataType = typeof(string), MaxLength= 60},
        new DataColumn{ ColumnName = "ServerName", DataType =  typeof(string), MaxLength = 60}
    }
};
```

In log4net, I used to set it as following:

```
private string serverName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
...
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Server"] = serverName;
```

Comment: @ElasticCode I am sorry but it looks like you did not understand my question. Thanks but no thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite straightforward and it kinda dawned upon me. I am not sure if I should use a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog.enrichers.environment/) for this but it took just 2 more lines of code, to get it working:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("ServerName", Environment.MachineName or System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()) // whatever you need to log
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production")
    ... // rest of the code in Startup.cs
```